# Is there a way to write a full vCard via NFC?

Tags: nfc, vcard

Is there a way to write a full vCard to a NFC tag?  All of the apps I've tried off Google Play seem to only write the email address or other subset.  I've tried apps such as NFC Task Launcher, NFC TagWriter by NXP and NFC Classic Tag Reader/Writer.

I'd like to write a vCard with one or two urls, a note field, phone number, email, name, and title. And yes, it's under the storage limit for the tag.

Comment: Can you just write the contents of the file as text?

Comment: I don't know, I was going to try that later.  I thought there was a mime type associated with the data so it would be interpreted as a vCard and not just a note.  But I will test it.

Answer (score 3):

I've found NFC Tools to be a good app for this.  You can write several default tag types, but they also offer a "raw" format, where you specify the mime type/header and content directly.  I was able to make a Version 3 vcard with a small PNG image included which worked well on several android devices.  Just be sure your vcard format is in spec when you do that, and be careful of space issues.  Most NFC tags can't hold more than a few hundred bytes, most on the market are under 1K.

Answer (score 3):

if you have an app like NFC Tools or a manual reader/writer, you can add a custom/manual data record and use text/vcard as the content type.

For the data field, just paste your vcard data like:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
FN:Your Name
TEL;CELL:(123) 555-1212
EMAIL;WORK:123@yahoo.com
ORG:Company Name
TITLE:Your Title
URL:google.com
URL:fb.com/username
URL:twitter.com/username
END:VCARD
```

That's it! then just write to your chip. you don't need http or https unless you have redirect issues with your domain. i'm able to make my links and social feeds work without it. every character adds up. you can list as many urls as you'd like. there are other fields you can add as per the vcard standards u can look up, but i believe, these are the ones android and apple understand.

I experimented with photo encoding and could not get it with NFC. 2KB! lol way too big. I was able to link to a vcard with a photo. I even tried the URL method for inserting photos and that didn't work. I hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for the example, this worked perfectly for me, after deleting a few rows as my tag is only NTAG 213.

Answer (score 2):

In [NFC Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.wdnfc), there is a simple contact option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It must be user error, because NXP TagWriter and Tagstand Writer both let me select fields from a contact to include now.  I did switch to a contact in the phone as opposed to browsing for a vcf file.